# How can I prevent execution of function when I expect that function to have been called in jest?

Tags: unit-testing, jestjs, jasmine

```
export function abc(){
         a();
}
export function a(){
     b();
}
export function b(){
 //do some tasks
}
import * as p from './filename'
it('a should call b',()=>{
 spyOn(p,'b');
 p.a();
 expect(p.b).toHaveBeenCalled();
);
```

When I try to execute this test case it tries to execute the b function as well and fails. I just want that it should call b function. How can I achieve that?

Answer (score 0):

Try with adding mockImplementation

// I am mocking b function and returning o as o/p of b()

```
const spyB = jest.spyOn(p, 'b').mockImplementation(0 as any);  
p.a();
expect(spyB).toHaveBeenCalled();  
spyB.mockClear();
```

Comment: its saying expected number of calls => 1

Comment: received no of calls => 0

Comment: that actually means, the function is not called

Comment: yes but we want it to be called and also when I debugged it , it is going into that function

Comment: did it executed original function?, please check the o/p. it should not

Comment: make sure you called a() after mocking the b(). I have updated my answer

Comment: it is executing the original function